# Multiple edits and community wiki

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

If I remember well, in the past a post edited more than 10 times became automatically community wiki. Nowadays I've seen [a post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882745/the-lattice-points-of-a-f-g-rational-cone-form-a-f-g-monoid) edited 15 times and nothing happened. Should I deduce that the rule was abrogated?

I think it is not nice to leave the users the possibility to edit their posts how many times they want since we all know that some of them are using this only for bumping up their question on the front page in order to draw attention.

Comment: This feature was changed some time ago. It was announced, I don't recall if it was announced on this meta as well, but I think it was.

Comment: Here is the relevant Stack Exchange Blog post: [Putting the Community back in Wiki](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/).

Comment: See also here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4368/edits-and-community-wikis/13721#13721 and here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/744/when-does-a-post-become-a-community-wiki-post/745#745

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The old auto-conversion to CW was replaced by an automatic flag. So the moderators are notified if a user misuses the edit ability in this way.

I think individual actions by moderators are preferable to a dumb automatic mechanism. There are valid reasons to edit more than 10 times and those should not be punished.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know!